# Django accessing ForeignKey model objects

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have the following:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

class License(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
```

and in a custom management command, I'm pulling in all the Employee objects with `employees = Employee.objects.all()`... how can I access associated License objects for each employee object? I have seen questions that talk about using ContentType for this purpose, but I'm confused on it's practical use. Can anyone provide an example on how to use ContentType (or another solution) in this context?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
employee.license_set.all()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Comment: You could add the related_name example: employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='licenses')

Comment: I read that earlier, but it didn't click. Easy beyond belief. Thanks! :)

Comment: I was importing all the models and constructing for loops for each one within the employees object... silly :)