# Django getting foreign-key object list

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have model like this:

```
class A:
....


class B:
....
a = model.ForeignKey(A, related_name='a')
....
```

Let's assume there is an B object.
I can get A object like this:

```
b = B()
a = b.a
```

Then what is the simplest way to get all B object related with A?

Additionally,
I can get a list of A.

```
list_a = A.objects.filter()
```

Then what is the simplest way of getting a list of B which relates with A object in the list_a?

One more reverse case: I have a list of B:

list_b = B.objects.filter()

Then what is the simplest and optimized way to get the list of A object related to the B object in the list_b?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622047/django-accessing-foreignkey-model-objects, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233883/get-all-related-django-model-objects?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
B.objects.filter(a__in=a_list)
```

note that you can filter on related objects like this (instead if executing two queries do it in one)

for example if your a_list is a query like this:

```
a_list = A.objects.filter(field=2)
```

you can filter B like this:

```
B.objects.filter(a__field=2)
```

which is more readable and also django can optimize it too)

Update: you can query reversed relations the same way

```
A.objects.filter(b__in=b_list)
A.objects.filter(b__field=2)
```

note that it's better to change your code to

```
a = model.ForeignKey(A, related_name='b')
```

`b` is the name of the field in reveres relations so `an_a_instance.b.all()` returns all instances of `b` which are pointing at given `a_instance`

Comment: Thanks, @aliva for a quick answer. Then how about a reverse case: 
list_b=B.objects.filter() How can get the A object list which is related with B?

Comment: I tried it, but I am getting this error:
"Cannot resolve keyword 'b' into field." because A object doesn't have a field named 'b'

Comment: sorry it's based on my note about changing related_name to 'b',

Comment: B object has A object as a foreign key. So your code should be 
b=model.ForeignKey(A, related_name='b') right? Then A.objects.filter(b__in=b_list) will work?

Comment: I think you should check this link to see how django related relations work https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects