# Is there a way to select specific fields from model in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is there a way to select some specific fields from model with Foreign Key. Here is an example:
let's say I have

```
class Product(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
            ('A', 'A'),
            ('B', 'B'),
            ('C', 'C'),
            )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
            ('Work Under Progress', 'Work Under Progress'),
            ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
            )

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, 
        choices=STATUS) 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

The purpose is to get the product name and product price in the Order class.
Is there any way to do so? (I'm very new to Django and could find exactly this in the doc)

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django accessing ForeignKey model objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622047/django-accessing-foreignkey-model-objects)

Comment: @UtkarshGupta not really, maybe I'm not asking the question the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can query for example with:

```
from django.db.models import F

orders = Order.objects.annotate(
    product_name=F('product__name'),
    product_price=F('product_price')
)
```

The `Order` objects that arise from *this* queryset, will have two extra attribute `.product_name` and `.product_price` that contains the `name` and the `price` of te related `Product`.

In the `Order` object itself, you can just use `self.product.name`. You already *do* that, for example in the `__str__` method. You can for example fetch the `name` and `price` of the related `product` with:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
            ('Work Under Progress', 'Work Under Progress'),
            ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
            )

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, 
        choices=STATUS) 
    def __str__(self):
        if self.product_id is not None:
            return '{}: {}'.format(self.product.name, self.product.price)
        else:
            return 'no_product'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but for some reason it is not working it is giving me this error    return '{}: {}'.format(self.product.name, self.product.price)
                                                                ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation. With this solution, does product_name and price become attributes of Order? actually this is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I found somehow something similar in here

[Django ForeignKey limit_choices_to a different ForeignKey id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578559/django-foreignkey-limit-choices-to-a-different-foreignkey-id)

I'll implement this solution and see if it works for me